# How to get around the problem that in R the event date is outside observations and R automatically selects the next observation point after the event?

Tags: r

I have the following problem concerning my dataset:

I have intraday data observations and I would like to match these with current event dates to perform an event study. In order to do this I need the events matching with the observation data. And there comes the problem..

How do you get around the problem that in R the event date is outside the observations and that R automatically selects the next observation point after the event?

This is the company side:

```
Symbol  date    time     Close
A   12.03.2020  06:00   65,542503
A   12.03.2020  07:00   72,334999
A   12.03.2020  08:00   63,857498
A   12.03.2020  09:00   65,057499
A   12.03.2020  10:00   67,4925
A   12.03.2020  11:00   66,552502
A   12.03.2020  12:00   65,215
A   12.03.2020  13:00   66,6675
A   12.03.2020  14:00   62,195
```

And this is the event side:

```
Symbol    date          time
A         12.03.2020    04:34
```

I tried this:

```
Companies_Events <- merge (Companies, Eventdates, by = c("Symbol", "date", "time") , all = FALSE)
```

But it is not working..

Do you have an idea how this could be working in R?

Comment: Create a proper datetime variable (`POSIXct`) and do a rolling join with `data.table`: `stock[event, on = .(Symbol, datetime), roll = -Inf]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the join, `filter`, `arrange` the data and select the 1st row for each `Symbol` and `date`.

```
library(dplyr)

Companies %>%
  left_join(Eventdates, by = c("Symbol", "date")) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('time'), as.POSIXct, format = '%H:%M')) %>%
  arrange(Symbol, date, time.x) %>%
  group_by(Symbol, date) %>%
  filter(time.x > time.y) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('time'), format, format = '%H:%M'))

# Symbol date       time.x Close     time.y
#  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>     <chr> 
#1 A      12.03.2020 06:00  65,542503 04:34
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you also know how it could work when I have more than one Symbol and more than one event for each Symbol?

Comment: This answer should work for that. It should give you one row for each `Symbol` and each `date`.